# Getting git items for a particular branch/tag via TFS rest api

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

Now that TFS 2015 comes with the same new Rest API of VS Team Services, I've taken a look at the API doc:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/git/overview

One question naturally raised is that most queries do not expose an parameter for git branch or tag (e.g. download /path/to/my/file with tag 'release_v1.0'), which looks like a show stopper. As in my case, I need programatically pull out some source file under a certain branch/tag.

Is it not supported yet?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. As or the link that you have above you can use the provided so to retrieve both branches and yes. In git they are really all the same thing, pointers. This use the "refs" api.

https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/git/refs